# Gmail Batch Send

Tags: node.js, gmail-api

I'm building a tool that makes use of the Sheets and Gmail APIs to pull a contact list and relevant data from a spreadsheet, build personalized emails for each contact from the data that pertains to them, and then send each contact their email.

This is all already working. My only remaining problem is that we can only send about 7 emails before the API returns a rate limit exceeded error on the rest of the contacts. Currently I'm building the emails and then looping through the email array to send each one using gmail.users.messages.send:

```
gmail.users.messages.send({
  auth,
  'userId': 'me',
  'resource': {
    'raw': email
  }
```

I'd like to instead batch these requests but the documentation I'm able to find on that doesn't appear to be in JS and I'm relatively new to coding in general so reading other languages and understanding how to perform similar operations in JS is a little difficult. Are there any resources for this kind of request specific to JS?

Comment: Not sure whether your issue is how to overcome the rate limits or how to send emails in batch. Could you pls elaborate?

Comment: Both I guess. I'd like to send the requests as a batch to avoid the rate limit since it should only count as 1 request towards the limit, or am I thinking that batch requests work differently than they do?

Comment: I'm not sure about gmail specific rate limits. If the limits are set per user and the number of emails that can be sent within a given time, I don't think batching the requests would help. But, if the limits are based on the number of API requests that can be made within a given time, then batching them would most likely resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do one of either an exponential backoff, per google's guidelines, as seen here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/backoff

or you can write an error = error.Http.Errors then use an if statement for if (error.response.status == 403 (which is user rate limit exceeded http response), then sleep for several seconds, else return OK and proceed.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping to avoid this since I was able to use batch requests for accessing spreadsheets and docs, but I've gone with your latter suggestion and it works great.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out for you. If I helped solve your issue, would you mind marking this answer as best answer for your question.